# If statement not met, even though it should be

Tags: rust

I am making an overtime pay calculator in rust. I have the following code below:

```
let overhours = 40;
let overhoursFLOAT = overhours as f32;

if calcpay > overhours{
    println!("You worked more than 40 hours!");
    let overmath = floathours - overhoursFLOAT as f32; 
    println!("You worked {} extra hours.",overmath);
    let overpay = overmath * 1.5;
    floatpay = floatpay + overpay;
}
else{println!("You did not work more than 40 hours. Therefore, your overtime pay will not be calculated.");}
```

Everytime i run it, the hours i input (I do 10) is under 40, and the if statement code runs anyway. It ends up looking like this:

```
How much do you get paid per hour?: 9
Hourly pay: 9
How much did you work?: 10
Hourly pay: 9
Hours worked: 10
Your calculated pay is $90
You worked more than 40 hours!
You worked -30 extra hours.
```

Am i using the operators wrong? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing calcpay with overhours and calcpay equals 90. I assume what you wanted is to compare overhours with hours worked instead.